# SaltStack how to segregate states between different teams?

Tags: salt-stack

Not sure if I'm asking this correctly, but how can you separate states between different teams. As in, how can an infrastructure team use Salt to build out machines (add users, networking, etc) and keep their states separate from a release engineering team's states (installing applications, 3rd party dependencies, etc).

Ideally, I would like to be able to keep the states separate enough that release engineering could run a high state that will apply all of their states across the environment while infrastructure could have a separate high state to apply their states to the environment.

Is this possible? Any chance anyone can point me in the direction of some documentation that goes over how to build this out?

Comment: Hi,one way you could work around this is using nodegroups and targeting through them.By targeting through them I mean in the `top.sls` file you could `match` on the nodegroups.

Comment: Does this help you at all?

Comment: Well, release engineering would be working on the same servers as infrastructure. So, node groups may be named differently, but they would pick up the same servers. If you match on nodegroup1 and it contains the same servers as nodegroup2, wouldn't your states effectively be applied against nodegroup1 and nodegroup2? Or, do you mean that you are really filtering the states by nodegroup, so the infrastructure states would only run if the infrastructure nodegroup was used, and the same goes for release engineering's node group?

Comment: I was kinda meaning the second part